# MySQL JOIN vs LIKE - faster selects?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-like

Okay, so first of all let me tell a little about what I'm trying to do. Basically, during my studies I wrote a little webservice in PHP that calculates how similar movies are to each other based on some measurable sizes like length, actors, directors, writers, genres etc. The data I used for this was basically a collection of data accquired from omdbapi.com.

I still have that database, but it is technically just a SINGLE table that contains all the information to each movie. This means, that for each movie all the above mentioned parameters are divided by commas. Therefore I have so far used a query that encapsulates all these things by using LIKE statements. The query can become quite large as I will pretty much query for every parameter within the table, sometimes 5 different LIKE statements for different actors, the same for directors and writers. Back when I last used this, it took about 30 to 60 seconds to enter a single movie and receive a list of 15 similar ones.

Now I started my first job and to teach myself in my freetime, I want to work on my own website. Because I have no real concept for what I want to do with it, I thought I'd get out my old "movie finder" again and use it differently this time. 
Now to challenge myself, I want the whole thing to be faster. Understand, that the data is NEVER changed, only read. It is also not "really" relational, as actor names and such are just strings and have no real entry anywhere else. Which essentially means having the same name will be treated as the same actor.

Now here comes my actual question:
**Assuming I want my select queries to operate faster, would it make sense to run a script that splits the comma divided strings into extra tables (these are n to m relations, see attempt below) and then JOIN all these tables (they will be 8 or more) or will using LIKE as I currently do be about the same speed?** The ONLY thing I am trying to achieve is faster select queries, as there is nothing else to really do with the data.

[image: database structure]
[image: movies structure]

This is what I currently have. Keep in mind, I would still have to create tables for the relation between movies + each of these tables. After doing that, I could remove the columns in the movie table and would end up having to join a lot of tables with EACH query. The only real advantage I can see here, is that it would be easier to create an index on individuals tables, rather than one (or a few) covering the one, big movie table.

I hope all of this even makes sense to you. I appreciate any answer short or long, like I said this is mostly for self studies and as such, I don't have/need a real business model.

Comment: Read the question: **[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)** Short answer: **Yes, it's really that bad.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand what you currently have. It seems that you only showd the size of tables but not its internal structure. You need to separate data into separate tables using normalization rules and then put correct indexes. Indexes will make your queries very fast. What does the sizing above your query mean? Have you ever run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for you queries, and please post the query I cannot guess your query out of the result. There are a lot of optimization videos on YT.

Comment: I added in a picture showing what table I currently have. What you said is basically what I was thinking, I've just learned that JOINs will make everything noticably slower, so I'm not sure if normalizing data (which technically isn't even relational, as I explained it's only strings, nothing unqiue) will bring a significant increase in speed over just staying away from JOINs and using LIKE a column that divides values by commas.

Comment: In present situation you have sequential scan (scanning all table). And using indexes is multitude faster. Is is faster to find word by reading book from cover to cover, or find it by using index at the end of the book?

Comment: JOINS are not inherently slow and I don't understand "using LIKE column". Or does it mean that you have several  `LIKE` expression that are slow. Take some query and run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE query' and you will see what exact operation your database (query planner) is doing.